# How to remove node from xml?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom

I have xml:

```
<Info>
    <info_1/>
    <info_2/>
    <info_3>
        <i ID="1"/>
        <i ID="2"/>
        <i ID="3"/>
    </info_3>
    <info_4>
    </indo_4>
</Info>
```

I need to delete a specific node in info_3, for example a node in which ID = 1, how can I do this?

I tried to do this, but log shows before and after length = 3 :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(bb)));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();  

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("i");  
Log.e("LOG", "nList.getLength() = " + nList.getLength());
Node node=nList.item(1);  
node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);  
Log.e("LOG", "nList.getLength() = " + nList.getLength());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that helped me:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(bb)));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();  

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("i");  
Log.e("LOG", "nList.getLength() = " + nList.getLength());
Set<Element> targetElements = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nList_Loan_guarantor.getLength(); i++) {
  Element e = (Element)nList_Loan_guarantor.item(i);
  if ("10938".equals(e.getAttribute("ID"))) {
  targetElements.add(e);
  }
}

for (Element e: targetElements) {
   e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);
   }

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList_2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("i"); 
Log.e("LOG", "nList.getLength() = " + nList.getLength());
```